# How to find largest group of consecutive numbers

Tags: google-sheets

This is a complex ask, so I apologize if it's unclear and will be happy to clarify. I have a series of numbers (dice rolls, in this case), and I need a formula to do the following:

1. Find groups of consecutive SAME numbers (i.e. two or more 1's in a row)
2. identify the largest of those groups
3. count how many occurrences of that number are in the largest group

And just to clarify, I don't need all three of those as output - I just need #3 as a number.

I've made a copy of the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CS9gxUvRAgFFyKjsyrQHgXDZKaUyYvzC16sCZED1a7Y

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this:

```
=arrayformula(let(
dicesides,20,
results,tocol(A2:A,1),
rollnum,sequence(counta(results)),
streaks_,lambda(x,frequency(if(results=x,rollnum),if(results=x,0,rollnum))),
maxstreakperdiceside,map(sequence(dicesides),lambda(roll,max(streaks_(roll)))),
max(maxstreakperdiceside)))
```

For each side of the dice, we are calculating the lengths of all the streaks of that side that are observed in the results, then calculating the maximum streak length per side, then finally calculating the maximum of the maximums.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Thank you so much, very much appreciated!